# Example shapefiles containing PointM, MultiPointM, PolygonM or PolylineM data

Tags: shapefile, data

I have written a Delphi library for reading shapefiles. Now I'd like to test it with some real data, but cannot find any shapefiles containing the "M" variety of data:

- PointM, MultiPointM, PolygonM or PolylineM
- and also "Z" data (PointZ, MultiPointZ, PolygonZ or PolylineZ) including the optional "M" data.

Any hints where I can get some test data of this kind?

https://gis.utah.gov/data/sgid-transportation/roads-system/ apparently links to some files but the ftp server times out on me.

Comment: There are some small shapefiles in the GDAL autotest directory https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/data.

Comment: @user30184 thanks, that helped a bit (and of course I found a bug :-( )

Comment: In fact, I found multiple bugs. :-(

Comment: ... but hey, that was the point. :-)

Comment: Could the downvoters please tell me their reasons?